# Class storing pointers to vector in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, operator-keyword

I'm implementing a class Aviary, which can store pointers to Bird-objects. Now, I have the following:

```
class Aviary {

public:
    const Bird &operator[](const size_t index) const {
    return birds[index];
    }

    Bird &operator[](const size_t index) {
    return birds[index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<Bird*> birds;
```

The Bird-objects are stored as pointers in order to avoid object-slicing. However, there is a problem with the operator[]-implementation (Reference to type 'const Bird' could not bind to an lvalue of 'const value_type' (aka 'Bird *const')).

How do I implement the operator[] properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dereference:

```
return *(birds[index]);
```

`birds[index]` is a `Bird*`, so you can't directly return it as a `Bird&`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you store pointers, you should `dereference` the pointer for return reference.

```
const Bird &operator[](const size_t index) const {
return *birds[index];
}

Bird &operator[](const size_t index) {
return *birds[index];
}
```

Side note: use smart pointers, instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Two side notes:

1. The `const` in a parameter passed by value (`const size_t index`) is useless and your compiler will ignore it. You can try declaring it with `const` and removing the `const` in the implementation: the compiler will correctly consider that your implementation matches the declaration.
2. The canonical way to implement the non-`const` version of `operator[]` is as follows:

As follows

```
Bird &operator[](size_t index) {
  return const_cast<Bird&>(const_cast<const Aviary*>(this)->operator[](index));
}
```

I know all those `const_cast` look ugly, but they are both safe and this is the right way to ensure that both versions of `operator[]` do the same (you just need to maintain the `const` version from now on), while also making sure that your are not doing any non-`const` operation in the `const` version.

Apart from that, the problem with your code is that you are returning pointers, not (references to) the values pointed by them, as Luchian and ForEveR have already pointed out.